# How to load a photo in img src from a folder in docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, flask, docker-compose

I have a react.js-flask app, which flask app is in a docker, and all my images are inside of a folder on backend side. When I try to load an image it can't find it and return 404 error.
Here is my docker-compose settings. Everything looks fine except fetching image file from docker.

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    ....
  redis:
    ....
  migrate:
    ....
  api:
    build: .
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - files:/app/files
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - migrate
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: ....
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379
    env_file:
      - ./.env

volumes:
  dbdata:
  files:
```

It returns this error

```
GET
http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/test_image/1.jpg
```

I changed 127.0.0.1 to localhost, nothing happened

Comment: What puts content in the `files` named volume?  Is the image file in your compiled image (and hidden by the volume mounts), or in the host filesystem, or somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't understand, what do you mean? I keep all files that users upload inside of the files folder and I store the path of those images in my db table. I created that volume because I wanted to mount that folder and use it in my local app.